# Using zip() Combining two lists into a dictionary with same keys in appand multipal values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two list and i try to combining in one `dict`

```
list1 = ['sys_time', 'sys_time', 'sys_time']
list2 = ['2018-03-16T11:00:00.000-07:00', '2018-03-12T00:00:00.000-07:00', '2018-03-14T00:00:00.000-07:00']

dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

**output :**

```
{'sys_time': '2018-03-14T00:00:00.000-07:00'}
```

how to I combining same keys in appand multipal values
like that :

```
{'sys_time': ['2018-03-16T11:00:00.000-07:00', 2018-03-12T00:00:00.000-07:00, '2018-03-14T00:00:00.000-07:00']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the keys are all the same (i.e sys_time)

```
list1 = ['sys_time1', 'sys_time2', 'sys_time3']
list2 = ['2018-03-16T11:00:00.000-07:00', '2018-03-12T00:00:00.000-07:00', '2018-03-14T00:00:00.000-07:00']

dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

but if you insist that they share the same key, one could associate keys with lists for values like so:

```
list1 = ['sys_time', 'sys_time', 'sys_time']
list2 = ['2018-03-16T11:00:00.000-07:00', '2018-03-12T00:00:00.000-07:00', '2018-03-14T00:00:00.000-07:00']
d = {}
for k,v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k] = d.get(k, []) + [v]
print(d)
```

Comment: yes but it is possible to zip with same keys to append multipal  values?

Comment: yes but not with zip, the values would have to be lists

Comment: added it for you

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what do you mean but considering combining two dict with each other like the output can be done like this code below:

```
x = ['sys_time', 'sys_time', 'sys_time']
y = ['2018-03-16T11:00:00.000-07:00', '2018-03-12T00:00:00.000-07:00', '2018-03-14T00:00:00.000-07:00']
dict = {x[0] : y[::]}
print(dict)
```